# Rails, Paperclip & S3: The specified key does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've got Paperclip configured like so:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

But my uploads' urls 404 with:

```
The specified key does not exist.
```

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: What is a real link to question_mark.jpg? Find this file at amazon, and research the links.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... do you want me to upload the image in the example somewhere that you can see it?

Comment: No, just ensure that folder /femail_users exists. Maybe this folder is a key

Comment: Are you sure the file has been uploaded by Paperclip to S3? If not, the issue could be with your paths?

Comment: @RichPeck How would I verify? Paperclip does not give me any errors saying upload failed, so I've been assuming it worked.

Comment: Did you set your env keys correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

It would mean that file doesn't exist on Amazon S3 to where you are point the image url to. Did you check the url path?